# How can we access and print the contents of DX:AX in Assembly language?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

When we use `mul` instruction in assembly and give it `BX` as a parameter, it multiplies `BX` with `AX` and stores the result in `DX:AX` and I want to print this result but do not know the EXACT instructions. Somebody please help me. I am using assembly for pentium processor!

Comment: You will need to convert the number to ASCII digits and then use a system call to output each ASCII character to the output. The system call depends upon what system you are on (Linux, DOS, etc). If you do a search on stackoverflow.com or Google, you should be able to find lots of examples of converting binary to decimal in assembly language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    mov cx,dx
    shl ecx,16
    mov cx,ax
```

ECX now contains the result of your multiplication.